# How to filter a sequence and retain evaluated pred values?

Tags: clojure

This is a scenario I encountered many times, yet didn't find an idiomatic approach for it...

Suppose one would like to use a self-defined `self-pred` function to filter a seq. This `self-pred` function returns `nil` for unwanted elements, and useful information for wanted elements. It is desirable to keep the evaluated `self-pred` values for these wanted elements.

My general solution is:

```
;; self-pred is a pred function which returns valuable info
;; in general, they are unique and can be used as key
(let [new-seq (filter self-pred aseq)]
   (zipmap (map self-pred new-seq) new-seq))
```

Basically, it is to call `self-pred` twice on all wanted elements. I feel it is so ugly...

Wonder if there is any better ways. Much appreciated for any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i use this kind of snippet:

```
(keep #(some->> % self-pred (vector %)) data)
```

like this:

```
user> (keep #(some->> % rseq (vector %)) [[1 2] [] [3 4]])
;;=> ([[1 2] (2 1)] [[3 4] (4 3)])
```

or if you like more verbose result:

```
user> (keep #(some->> % rseq (hash-map :data % :result)) [[1 2] [] [3 4]])
;;=> ({:result (2 1), :data [1 2]} {:result (4 3), :data [3 4]})
```

Answer (score 5):

In these scenarios you can use `keep`, but you have to change your "predicate" function to return the full information you need, or `nil`, for each item.

For example:

```
(keep (fn [item] 
         (when-let [tested (some-test item)] 
           (assoc item :test-output tested))) aseq)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with `keep`, but would just use plain map & filter like so:

```
(def data (range 6))

(def my-pred odd?)

(defn zip [& colls] (apply map vector colls))  ; like Python zip
(defn filter-with-pred
  [vals pred]
  (filter #(first %)
    (zip (map pred vals) vals)))

(println (filter-with-pred data my-pred))
```

with result:

```
([true 1] [true 3] [true 5])
```

Answer (score -1):

If self-pred guarantees no duplicate key creation for differing values then I'd reach for reduce (since assoc the same key twice will override the original key value pair):

```
(reduce #(if-let [k (self-pred %2)]
          (assoc %1 k %2)
          %1)
 {}
 aseq)
```

Else we can use group-by to drive a similar result:

```
(dissoc (group-by self-pred aseq) nil)
```

Although not the same since the values will be in vectors: {k1 [v1 ..], k2 [..], ..}. but this guarantees all values are kept.

Comment: Could you explain what's going on here a little and how it replaces the code in the question?